# How to save json as vertex properties values

Tags: json, graph, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am trying to save a json as a vertex's property value. Below is my query.

```
String createVrtx = "g.addV('Person').property('id','123').property('Address','{"City":"bang","pin": "123456"}')";
```

if i convert the json as string it works but when i try to parse output it becomes difficult any idea .

does gremlin support json type as property type.

Is it possible to add properties to a property 
like above 
address is a property and it values city has property bang etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meta-properties (properties of properties) are not supported in Amazon Neptune. The better way to do this would be to have `Address` as its own vertex, add the properties to it, and then link it to the `Person` vertex via a `hasAddress` edge. It also gives you more flexibility from a query perspective as well.